# Stop user scroll to set position on RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

So I've got a problem, i'm quite new to android programming, it's been only 6-8 weeks since i've started programming android apps so i may be blind and not see the easy answer but here's my problem:

I'm making a school project and i'm trying to develop a similar calendar to the one in Today's Calendar split view (The one below here)

[image: Image 1]

So i've made a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager that looks like this:

[image: Image 2]

And up until here everything's fine, but i'm trying to implement the button that sets the calendar on today's date, the thing is that when i'm scrolling with a fling and then set the RecyclerView position with scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0); the view keeps the momentum gained from the first fling, sets the position and then keeps on scrolling until the momentum is gone

I've searched a lot to find a solution, when i was using gridView instead of RecyclerView i used smoothScrollToPositionFromTop() which stopped the scrolling and then the setSelection() to position it, but the gridView skipped frames and i had to change, here with RecyclerView there is no smoothScrollToPositionFromTop and smoothScrollToPosition doesn't stop the scroll, neither does scrollToPosition or scrollToPositionWithOffset.

found this but doesn't help [Scroll RecyclerView to show selected item on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top)

and many others that didn't help.

I considered implementing my own scrolling logic but when i looked into it my head exploded and i wouldn't know where to begin.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Did you know that `RecyclerView` has a `stopScroll()` method to stop a scroll in progress?

Comment: Oh my god i'm facepalming so hard right now :_) thank you very much. As soon as i can test it i'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: Hey, I've been bashing computers into submission for 30 years and still have a daily facepalm.  Cheers

Comment: Do you happen to know why the smoothscroll method of the recyclerView lags a lot when used on pre lollipop especially when using textViews?

Comment: When you say "lags", are you getting stutters in the scroll motion?  I would make sure there isn't any logic executing on the UI thread that should be pushed off onto a background thread before suspecting the platform.  I do get a lot of jerky behavior when running with an emulator or even having the device hooked up to the debugger, but running normally on a device I don't see that.

Comment: I tried it on a blank activity with static content on the cell just a textview with "aaa" and on lollipop works just fine but on pre lollipop stutters a lot, it's almost like I used scrollTo instead of smoothScrollTo. When i used all Imageviews with ic_launcher instead of the textviews the stutter diminished a lot

Comment: Thank you very much, i've put my code here https://github.com/sedestrian/Scroll-Test is just a basic recyclerview with static content cells. I hope i've put everything needed :)

Comment: I will try it out.  I was just thinking, I saw a demo animation for GMail in the Material Design docs, then when my GMail got updated I looked for the animation and it wasn't there. The app would have been using the support library since my tablet was still on KitKat.  So I suspect that Google took the lazy way out in the support lib and didn't make it as fully featured as the Lollipop platform code, especially concerning animations.

What I mean is the support library probably says, okay are we on Lollipop? then just pass off to the platform, otherwise do a not-as-good imitation.

Comment: That might be, but then why make the method smoothScroll available for pre Lollipop? (I forgot to tell you that to try my code i did it a little ghetto, so you'll have to tap Settings to start the scroll XD)

Comment: @kris larson :- Is there is any method to start scroll RecyclerView again after stopping?

Comment: @voidpointer I think the idea is that after stopping the scroll, you would use a method like `scrollToPositionWithOffset()` to move the list where you wanted, as in the OP's case.

Comment: Thanks bro ... You save may One day !!