# RecyclerView setSelected and scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In a `ListView`, `getListView().setSelection(n);` is used  for a direct scroll and `getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(n);` is used for a smooth scroll.

Is this possible in a `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Why not read the doc:https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use [scrollToPositionWithOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)).

```
//Scroll item 2 to 20 pixels from the top
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);
```

This question was [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876044/4871489).

Comment: Sorry for this bad question, but thanks, the answer is perfect for me :)

Comment: I found this answer when looking for the equivalent of ListView's `setSelectionFromTop`.