# Change the recyclerview's focus to certain item position?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

So I have a standard `RecyclerView` that takes a list of posts and displays them to the user. My problem is when the user comes into the activity, I want to be able to change the focus to a particular post.

Ex. User A sees that he has a notification that of someone has liked his/her post. He/she clicks that notification, and it loads the activity of user's post, and then the focus changes to the position of the post that had bee liked.

I pass in the `postID` to the activity using an intent. I then run the `Recycler View`, and `onBindHolder` i try to see if the post's ID matches to the `postID` I sent in via intent. If it does, I now set the activity's variable `postFocusPosition` to the position of that post.

Now I'm stuck on what that magic method i need to call in `RecyclerView` class to actually change the focus to that item position!

Hope someone can help enlighten me on that magic line(s) of code that changes focus!

Comment: Why not use a Scroll to Position? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top

Answer (score 13):

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mSkipTo); //use to focus the item with index
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

For smooth scrolling effect and to avoid any resizing issue of recyclerview items, you can use

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(itemposition); //you can get this position, from your adapter class through an interface method
```

As with "scrollToPosition", I was facing resizing issue of recyclerview items.

Note : You could use this method for both horizontal and vertical recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

just use this

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```