# How do I move selected items of recyclerview list to the top of recyclerview list

Tags: android

I am working on a RecyclerView there is one thing I want to know, How do I move selected positions or items of the recyclerview list to the top of the list in the recyclerview adapter itself.Any better suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: What have you done for this?

Comment: I am populating the list as per positions. If I select the 10th item it should jump to 0th position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll RecyclerView to show selected item on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top)

Answer (score 2):

try this first move your select item postion to top of your recyclerview like this

```
    ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList;
    DataModel model=arrayList.get(position);
    arrayList.remove(position);
    arrayList.add(0,model);
```

than  use **[scrollToPositionWithOffset (int position, 
                int offset)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int))** to move to top

> **scrollToPositionWithOffset** Scroll to the specified adapter position with the given offset from resolved layout start

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 10);
```