# LayoutManager setFirstVisibleItemPosition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am developing an app that load data inside recyclerview, when i scroll to top of my recyclerview (position 0) i will load more data, after loading new data recyclerview position changed, but i want to set FirstVisibleItemPosition manually,
is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can use recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)

Comment: this is not my solution because when i scroll to position(x), then "X"is last visible item and i want 
X" to be first visible item in recyclerview.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top] did you try?

Comment: @NhaPhạmThị yes itried,but not work what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by this solution
when i add some data to my adapter, i called

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(...);
```

that was wrong.then i changed it to

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(...)
```

and now it works.