# Android - recycler view scroll to position doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase then display it in recycler view. I set the layout to be reverselayout = true. However, when I run the activity, the view starts at the bottom. I tried to change the initial position when the application is run using scrollToPosition as commented below, but still nothing changes. Does anyone have a solution related to this problem?

I've tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876044/7825519
But still start from bottom.

```
mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    (mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).reverseLayout = true
    (mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).stackFromEnd = true
    mRecyclerView?.scrollToPosition(3)
//        mRecyclerView?.smoothScrollToPosition(3)
//        (mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(3,0)
//        mNestedScrollView?.scrollTo(0,3)
    mAdapter = DiscoverAdapter(mItems, mPostKey, Static.mLikedPosts, this)
    mRecyclerView!!.adapter = mAdapter
    val spacingInPixels = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_between_card)
    mRecyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels))
```

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

Comment: Do you want to start from the bottom? Because this is what you're asking with reverseLayout=true and stackFromEnd = true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll RecyclerView to show selected item on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top)

Comment: @mTak I want to start from a position other than the bottom position

Comment: Why do you set reverseLayout=true and stackFromEnd = true?

Comment: @Sphinx I've tried that before. But still doesn't work.

Comment: So comment out these 2 lines and try again

Comment: @mTak I try stackFromEnd = true and false nothing happen. I use reverselayout = true to reverse the order of my data from firebase. It works, but the scroll position starts from bottom. I want to change it from the other position

Comment: see my answer. I did not see that that you set the adapter after you try to scroll

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete the both lines that make the recyclerview start from the botom. 
Set the scrolling after you set the adapter:

```
mRecyclerView!!.adapter = mAdapter
mRecyclerView?.scrollToPosition(3)
```

Comment: Still start from bottom :(

Comment: Do they all fit to the screen? It would be better if you post an image of the starting screen

Comment: Are you sure the position of the item is 3?

Comment: yes. I try to start from position 0, 1, 2, mItems.size()-1. But nothing happen. Still start from bottom when reverseLayout = true.

Comment: Try  scrollToPosition(mItems.size()-3) or scrollToPosition(mItems.size()-4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `scrollToPosition` using `post` method of `View`