# Kotlin/RecyclerView: scrollToPositionWithOffset Not Showing Up

Tags: android, kotlin

I wish to understand why I can't seem to use the scrollToPositionWithOffset method on a LinearLayoutManager? Please see the image for what I mean :

[image: scrollToPositionWithOffset not found!]

A little background:

The first line in the image (with `scrollToPosition`) is scrolling the RecyclerView to make the position (in this case 50) **visible** - this often means that the selected position shows up at the bottom of the visible RecyclerView (where position 50 first becomes visible after 'scrolling'). Whereas I want to always show it at the top. From my research, a some-what solution seems to be to use this `scrollToPositionWithOffset` method ([Scroll RecyclerView to show selected item on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top))

Interestingly, I was able to achieve what I wanted by customizing SmoothScroller of LinearLayoutManager, but my dataset is huge so speed of 'smooth scrolling' is an issue, and I can't seem increase the speed enough without causing other issues.

In short, I'm hoping that scrollToPositionWithOffset will do the trick for me. However, I don't know how to access the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast the `LayoutManager` returned from `RecyclerView.getLayoutManager()`.

`(recyclerview.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset`

Comment: Thank you. It works. Does anyone know why this casting is needed for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
recyclerView.apply { 
      
    (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(itemPosition, offsetValue)

}
```

Note that **offsetValue** could be **X** if your list/recycleView has horizontal orientation or **Y** if your list/recycleView has vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a little more context to the other answers, `scrollToPositionWithOffset()` is not a method of LayoutManager (the base class), but one of LinearLayoutManager (and its subclasses). My assumption is that the reasoning here was that such a method is not necessarily applicable (or could be ambiguous) for other LayoutManagers. Suppose we have a more "exotic" layout manager which does not organize items as a simple list, but rather in a circular shape. What should the offset do in such a case? Does it represent an extra amount radians/degrees to add to the scroll? Or rather something else?

In the case of a LinearLayoutManager (and any derived classes), however, it is fairly clear what the offset should do. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that's why only LinearLayoutManagers have access to the method, hence requiring a cast of the RecyclerView's LayoutManager.