# make recyclerview item take sceen width and position it on click

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

Am working with google maps and I have a horizontal recyclerview on top of the map to show some Important information about some locations in the map I want when the user select some item to make it take the whole space ( match parent ) and am able to this by change the with to match parent inside onClickListner but I have two problems

1 - when select the first item everything is fine but when select the second one the width change but its half way off screen  I want to position it correctly

2- when any item selected the rest of items are being pulled up I guess because they are sticking to the top of the parent view , I have tried to set the gravity to bottom but it didn't work

[image: the horizontal recyclerview] [image: the second item when clicked]

map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
>

<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".maps.HospitalsSearchActivity" />

<include
    layout="@layout/hospital_map_overley"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />
```

the recyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/mapHospitals_recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
/>
```

the card view that inflated to the recycerview

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/hospital_logo"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hospital_logo"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            />
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hospital_name"
            style="@style/AppText"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_border" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_full" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_full" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_full" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_full" />
        </LinearLayout>
        
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/reserveNowBtn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/PrimaryButton"
            android:text="@string/reserve_now"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - when select the first item everything is fine but when select the
> second one the width change but its half way off screen I want to
> position it correctly

Options:

1. Hide all other views in the Recycler, example:

```
  private fun hideAllBut(itemId: String) {
    itemList.iterator().apply { 
      while (hasNext()) next().apply {
        if (id != itemId) itemList.indexOf(this).also { 
          layout.recycler.getChildAt(it).visibility = View.GONE
          layout.recycler.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(it)
  } } } }
```

2. Scroll the Recycler to item's position, example ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top)):

```
  // Scroll to item 2 with 20 pixels offset
  linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20)
```

> 2- when any item selected the rest of items are being pulled up I
> guess because they are sticking to the top of the parent view , I have
> tried to set the gravity to bottom but it didn't work

Be sure you are using the correct between `gravity` and `layout_gravity`, for example you want to use `android:gravity="bottom"` in the RecyclerView or `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` in the CardView. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/what-is-the-difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-in-android).