# Is there any UI component that works as an anchor on a Text View?

Tags: android, textview

I have a long scroll text in a text view I get from a text file and I want to create a menu that enables you to jump to a specific point in the text. I tried to set HTML href anchor links in the text file but it didn't work.

```
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(byteArrayOutputStream.toString()));
```

How do I create a menu of text paragraphs of a text view?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the paragraphs in a RecyclerView and then use [linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875061/scroll-recyclerview-to-show-selected-item-on-top) to scroll the RecyclerView to the chosen paragraph.